# Change active style of MUI table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a table where I can sort inputs as on the mui website under "sorting and selecting":
https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

What I want is to change the color of the header-text that is selected for sorting. I have tried the following, but only managed to change the background-color this way (simplified code example):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  active: {
    color: "yellow",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
});

function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // functions for sorting etc. here left out
  return (
  <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table>
          <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
               <StyledTableCell>
                    <TableSortLabel
                      active={valueToOrderBy === "column"}
                      direction={
                        valueToOrderBy == "column" ? orderDirection : "asc"
                      }
                      onClick={createSortHandler("column")}
                      classes={{ active: classes.active }}
                    >
                      column
                    </TableSortLabel>
                  </StyledTableCell>
                 </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
        // data that comes in the column
       </TableBody>
         </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        )}
```

So, when I click on the column, the column is sorted and background-color of the header-text changes to yellow, but not text color. I have tried changing the theme active and selected color, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same issue answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880835/material-ui-overriding-styles-with-increased-specificity/63881486#63881486).

The problem is that the color is defined in the `root&$active` selector. The `active` selector is only used as a "pseudo" selector as can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableSortLabel/TableSortLabel.js#L26).

The following code will override both properties correctly:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '&$active': {
      color: "yellow",
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
    },
  },
  active: {}, // pseudo
});

...

<TableSortLabel
  active={valueToOrderBy === "column"}
  direction={
    valueToOrderBy == "column" ? orderDirection : "asc"
  }
  onClick={createSortHandler("column")}
  classes={{ root: classes.root, active: classes.active }}
>
  column
</TableSortLabel>
```

See [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zdbgu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I get the logic, but it does not seem to work for me. This time, also the background-color does not come through. Any idea what could be wrong?
For instance if I set:
root: {
color: "yellow"
}
I do see the letters in yellow, but they turn back to black when selected.

Comment: Ah yes, I've updated the answer. The `active` className should also be set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could never have done this without your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTableSortLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: "coral",
          "&:hover": {
            color: "white"
          },
          "&.Mui-active": {
            "&&": {
              color: "white",

              "& * ": {
                color: "white"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        icon: {
          color: "white"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});


     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
{/* tableHead content*/}
    </ThemeProvider>
```

See [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tdtepf?file=/src/App.js)