# Material UI override styles with increased specificity

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I found [Material UI Overriding styles with increased specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880835/material-ui-overriding-styles-with-increased-specificity) question to be related to mine, but I couldn't transfer the solution to my problem.

I have a vertical `Slider` with marks and for the marks, I want to get rid of the text-transformation.

I am setting the styles like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    vertical: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
        transform: 'none',
        '&$markLabel': {
            transform: 'none'
        }
    },
    markLabel: {
        transform: 'none'
    },
}));
```

To use them with the `Slider` like this:

```js
  <Slider
      orientation="vertical"
      marks={marks}
      classes={{
        vertical: classes.vertical,
        markLabel: classes.markLabel
      }}
  />
```

Chrome DevTools reveal that `vertical`-styles get applied, but get overriden by a more specific class `.MuiSlider-marked.MuiSlider-vertical`:

[image]

Same happens for the text-transformation, which is again applied but overridden due to a more specific combination of two classes `.MuiSlider-vertical .MuiSlider-markLabel`:

[image]

I tried my luck with a `Theme`, but following approach didn't go well either:

```js
createTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiSlider: {
            markLabel: {
                transform: 'none'
            },
            vertical: {
                '&$markLabel': {
                    transform: 'none'
                },
            },
        }
    },
});
```

Any help would by highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is working for me and solving above issue:

`makeStyles`:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiSlider-markLabel': {
            transform: 'none',
            left: '-14px',
            marginBottom: '17px',
        }
    },
}));
```

`Slider`:

```js
<Slider
    orientation="vertical"
    marks={marks}
    classes={{
      vertical: classes.vertical,
    }}
    className={classes.root}
/>
```

Since `className` is setting the styles for `root`, it is essentially same as:

```js
<Slider
    orientation="vertical"
    marks={marks}
    classes={{
      vertical: classes.vertical,
      root: classes.root
    }}
/>
```